# Morphia: Create new Morphia instance for each database?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

In my initialization code right now, I create 1 `Morphia` instance and use it to map all my classes across all my databases.  I've noticed though that when I call `ensureIndexes()`, it will initialize an empty collection and index all the collections across all databases.

Is the correct pattern for this to instead create 1 `Morphia` instance per each database and then loop through each instance to ensureIndexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the one Morphia instance and create one Datastore for each db so long as they all share the same mapping information.

Comment: Right now I'm creating one Datastore per db using the single morphia instance.  But when I call datastore.ensureIndexes() on any of the instances, it creates indexes and collections for all the classes mapped to morphia.

Comment: Yes.  it will do that.  There's one Mapper per Morphia instance.  If you don't want every collection in every database, you'll need to break things up a bit.